# StrongLoop Roles Scenario

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I recently came across StrongLoop and am thinking of porting my existing app to it. However, I am unable to wrap my head around how the following scenario can be catered for:

My app is supposed to have two distinct regions `Retailer` and `Customer`. The UI and functionality for `Retailers` is very different from that for `Customers`.

The users, on the other hand, can have the roles `Retailer`, `Customer`, and even **both** `Retailer` and `Customer`. So when a user tries to log in, I check what roles she has assigned. If she has a single role, I redirect her to the appropriate section of the site.

If, however, she has multiple roles, I need to present her with a list of roles assigned to her where she needs to make a selection what role she wants to assume for this login. If she selects `Retailer`, I should redirect her to the `Retailer` section of the app where she should only be able to post products (let's say). If she selects `Customer`, I should redirect her to the `Customer` section of the app where she can only view the products posted by all retailers.

In a StrongLoop world, is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Did you have a look at my answer ? Your question is a bit wide, but I hope it helped a little bit. Don't hesitate if you need more clarification